# Fastest way to join multiple data tables from multiple functions - c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asynchronous

A function in my app is returning a data table by joining the data tables getting from many other sub functions. Each sub functions are independent to each other with common primary key. Now, It takes nearly two minutes to execute the function for 50 of students. Please suggest me a best/fastest way to achieve the same.

```
 public DataTable ShowReportOnGridivew(int class_id, string searchDate)
    {
        DataTable dt_students_List = null;
        try
        {

            //====Main Table=====//
            dt_students_List = GetDistinctStudentList(class_id);//there will be around minimum of 50 students
            if (dt_students_List != null)
                dt_students_List.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt_students_List.Columns["student_id"] };
            //Tables need to merge with main table
            DataTable dt_CurrentRank = null;
            DataTable dt_ScoreInEnglish = null;
            DataTable dt_AcademicDetails = null;
            DataTable dt_ExtraCurriculam = null;
            DataTable dt_Attendance = null;
            DataTable dt_Arts = null;
            DataTable dt_FuelToBridger = null;
            DataTable dt_FuelToAircraft = null;
            DataTable dt_TeacherFeedback = null;
            DataTable dt_TotalScore = null;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt_students_List.Rows)
            {
                string student_id = row["student_id"].ToString();//primary key
                //==========Current Rank================//
                dt_CurrentRank = GetCurrentRank(student_id);//Binding data using sql
                dt_CurrentRank.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt_CurrentRank.Columns["student_id"] };
                if (dt_CurrentRank != null)
                {
                     dt_students_List.Merge(dt_CurrentRank);
                }
                //====== Score in English =====
                dt_ScoreInEnglish = GetScoreInEnglish(student_id, searchDate);
                dt_ScoreInEnglish.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt_ScoreInEnglish.Columns["student_id"] };
                if (dt_ScoreInEnglish != null)
                {
                     dt_students_List.Merge(dt_ScoreInEnglish);
                }
                //====== Academic Details =====
                dt_AcademicDetails= GetAcademicDetails(student_id);
                dt_AcademicDetails.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt_AcademicDetails.Columns["student_id"] };
                if (ddt_AcademicDetails != null)
                {
                     dt_students_List.Merge(dt_AcademicDetails);
                }
                //=====Similarly calling other functions and merging the columns to dt_students_List ======
              
            }
        }
        catch (Exception show_error)
        {
            string log_data = "Response: Error- " + show_error.ToString();
            obj.DatalogFile("StudentsList", log_data);
            throw show_error;
        }
        return  dt_students_List;
    }



 ====== Each sub functions are written like below.=============
private async DataTable GetCurrentRank(string student_id)
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            SqlDataReader dr = null;
            string sql = string.Empty;

            sql = "SELECT  student_id,current_rank FROM student_details WHERE " +
              " student_id = @student_id   ";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_id", student_id);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt = new DataTable("CurrentRank");
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("student_id", typeof(int)),
                    new DataColumn("current_rank", typeof(float))});
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    dt.Load(dr);
                }
                string log_data = "Web App Function: GetCurrentRank \n";
                log_data += "Response: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
                obj.DatalogFile("GetCurrentRank", log_data);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception show_error)
            {
                string log_data = "Response: Error- " + show_error.ToString();
                obj.DatalogFile("GetCurrentRank", log_data);
                throw show_error;
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The fastest way is to do this in the database, not the client. Even better, use an ORM like EF to load all the related objects at once instead of executing a myriad queries one by one. *All* of this code can be replaced with a single LINQ query that returns a class's students and their related classes

Comment: Could you please show me a sample?I'm doing it inside the web api.

Comment: Check [EF Core - Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli). As long as the class and table names match and the column names follow conventions, (eg ID or BlogId for the primary key) EF can work without extra configuration. When you retrieve a root object and its related entities, eg a Class with its Students, EF will generate automatically the SQL query needed to load all of them and map the results to Class and Student objects

Comment: I'm doing in webforms. not in .net core . Will it be fast if implement the same with stored procedure?

Comment: EF works in .NET Framework as well. .NET Core appeared when EF was already at version 6. You'll find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/)

Answer (score -1):

You can write multiple select statement in single stored procedure;
and get output in DataSet.

You can get all your tables in a single request:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Demo
    **Parameters**
AS
    -- Your all functions select statements
GO;
```

**C#**:

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string ConnectionString, string SpName)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = SpName;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    ///conn.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
    ///conn.Close();

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: That's not a good answer on many levels. It doesn't answer the question. It leaks connections, adapters and commands. It doesn't establish relations between DataTables. That's simply not how ADO.NET is used.

Comment: As of my knowledge for performance improvement stored procedure is good in Ado.NET,If you have a better solution than that then provide so i will also know the new way

Comment: In companies you cannot directly change flow of coding. like removing Ado.NET and using EF, because of this i was trying to give the answer on that code basis which they shared

Comment: You didn't give any answer, just memory leaks. The code you posted doesn't add relations. It just loads multiple tables from multiple result sets. It's very bad ADO.NET code to begin with. It was bad 20 years ago, when Datasets were popular.

Comment: You don't need a stored procedure to execute multiple queries either. Nor does using a stored procedure make anything run faster. SQL Server will compile all queries into execution plans and cache them the first time they're executed, no matter where they come from.  To get the related records though you'd have to write multiple queries with complex JOINs though, from Class to Student to the other tables. That's missing from this answer

Comment: I didn't provide a join statement because I thought it had select statements written in each functions, he just need some modification to work that query as expected.

Comment: Can you give me a solution in form of EF core with the single query for followed criteria
I have a two tables ,if records are not present in first table then check in second table same condition applicable for both table to get records.