# Stored procedure to loop through data table and join results to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to populate all distinct values from a column of table (distinct `student_id` and corresponding rank) to a temp table of stored procedure.

And then I want to loop through this temp table (using `student_id`) and I need to execute multiple queries for each `student_id`.

The result of all this single query will contains `student_id` and other columns. I want to join this result set to the main temp table by considering this `student_id` as primary key.

In C# I can do this by using a `for` loop But it takes long time to execute. Please help me to how to write this in stored procedure.

Or is there a way I can get SQL results for all these student in a single query other than looping through it and have to merge this result to  `#maintable`. There are nearly 15 sub queries to execute and join to main table. It is not easy to write single query to join all this. Because the filtering parameter (where clause) for each query is different.

Actually I want this code converted into a stored procedure:

[C# code is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73046940/fastest-way-to-join-multiple-data-tables-from-multiple-functions-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment129014629_73046940)

Sample Tables are like below.

1.student_distinct_table
it will contain all students list. Both external and internal students.

```
auto_id  internal_stu_id   external_stu_id   standard     class_teacher    
 1       XXXX                  NULL             10         teachername1      
 2       YYYY                  NULL             9          teachername2      
 3       NULL                  DDDD             10         teachername3      
 4       NULL                  EEEE             8          teachername1      
 5       AAAA                  NULL             10         teachername1
```

2.student_daily_progress_table

```
  ref_auto_id     score    subject    last_updated_by
    1               100     Spanish     2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
    2                80     Arabi       2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
    1                90     English     2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
    2               100     Spanish     2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
    3               100     English     2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
    4               100     Arabi       2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
    4               100     English     2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
    4               100     Spanish     2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
```

3.student_extracurricular_table

```
ref_auto_id   score    sports_id       last_updated_by
1               100     1           2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
2                10     2           2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
1                20     3           2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
2               100     2           2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
3               50      1           2022-07-12 00:00:00.000
```

5.sports_item

```
sports_id  item_name
1          Cricket
2          Chess
3          FootBall
4          Badminton
5          VolleyBall
```

6. Output:
   The filtering parameters (where clause) are standard and last_updated_by
   so when filtering for standard 10 and date- 2022-07-12 00:00:00.000, the result should be like below.
   sports and subject(spanish,arabi,english) are static(cricket,chess,football) means no need to show more than this items.
   Columns with zero can also be shown as empty.

   ```
    auto_id student_id standard    teacher     tot_eng  tot_span  tot_arab tot_cric tot_chess  tot_foot  tot_sports
      1       XXXX        10       teachername1    90      100        0          100     0          20          120
      3       DDDD        10       teachername3   100       0         0           50     0           0           50
      5       AAAA        10       teachername1    0        0         0            0     0           0           0
   ```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Do you seriously need a loop? A single complex will likely perform much better than a loop. And really we need a [MRE] with sample data and desired results in order to assist. And if you do need a loop in SQL there are plenty of examples out there on how to do it.

Comment: `I need to execute multiple queries for each student_id.` Can you show us an example or two of these query.

Comment: please check the sample

Comment: Others are more likely to help if you provide easily consumable information in the form of a script or fiddle.